# AR Image Display Issue

Tags: image-processing, augmented-reality, display, vuforia

My company have a big issue with Vuforia Engine for the past 3 days.
When we scan a visual with our application, a blank screen appears before our content appears and there's a lot of latency. This wasn't the case before the update of the website.
Can you please help me ? Is anyone else in the same situation?
Thank you.

We tried to reduce the size of our files as they may have been too heavy, but it didn't help.